# 50% wdth inline-block divs side by side break on input child element

Tags: html, css

I am building a contact div (`.header__form-contact--wrapper`) which is split into 2 inline-blocks side by side: `.header__form-contact-left` and `.header__form-contact-right`, the left would be input fields and the right would be address, skype, facebook, etc.
inside `.header__form-contact-left` the inputs would be split as 3 inputs stacked  (name, tel, email) and another input (long text) with full height, I split them into 2 more inline-block elements as I want to be able to control height and contain them.

**HTML**

```
<div class="header__form-contact--wrapper">
    <div class="header__form-contact-left" style="white-space: nowrap">
        <div class="header__form-contact-input-right">
            <p>this is right</p>
        </div>
        <div class="header__form-contact-input-left">
            <p>this is left</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header__form-contact-right"></div>
</div>
```

and the **CSS**:

```
.header__form-contact--wrapper {
    height: 200px;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    &>div {
        border: 1px red solid;
        height: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

yet if I add `display: table` to all `p` elements, the breakage is pacified:

```
.header__form-contact--wrapper {
    & p {
        display: table;
    }
}
```

#### Yet when using `<input>` (opposed to `<p>`) table & table-cell doesn't work well.

**HTML**

```
<div class="header__form-contact--wrapper" >
    <div class="header__form-contact-left" style="white-space: nowrap">
        <div class="header__form-contact-input-right">
            <input>
            <input>
            <input>
        </div>
        <div class="header__form-contact-input-left">
            <input>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header__form-contact-right"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header__form-contact--wrapper {
    height: 200px;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    &>div {
        border: 1px red solid;
        height: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50%;
    }
    & input {
        display: table;
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

How can I use all those inline-block elements to be aligned well, preferrably not using table/table-cell.

Thanks,
Buddy

Comment: adding `display: table;` to your `<p>` wont do anything as they are wrapped. Are you "just" trying to have things side by side and center aligned?

Comment: _“the breakage is pacified”_ - sounds very poetic; no actual clue what you mean by it though.

Comment: Trying to display input fields “as” a table is just very very ridiculous to begin with IMHO.

Comment: @CBroe - poetic? That's English. re your 2nd comment, anything helpful/constructive to add to the issue? Thanks mate.

Comment: So what, just because its English doesn’t mean that it was self explanatory what you mean by it. Plus, you have not even given us a proper description of what you actually want to _achieve_ here ... you have only shown us how far you have already stumbled down the “hey, I know, tables are super for layouting” path ... _“anything helpful/constructive to add to the issue? ”_ - [ask]

Comment: @clusterBuddy first your html and css does not produce the result you have specified in the image and second why not just use `vertical-align:top` to the `inline-block` divs

Comment: what function does the `header__form-contact-input-right` have?

Comment: @Dejan.S question edited for clarity

Comment: @CBroe - Question at the end and post were edited to be more concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: flex;` to have things side by side, that also makes it easy to algin in both axis. I would recommend you to read this awesome article on [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) about Flexbox to get you started. Having to align things with `display: inline;` is (I would dare to say) always gone be complicated and you will turn to hacks like `font-size: 0;` to get rid of margins ect...

I did you a foundation so that you can build on it. Some of the `flex-property: value;` properties can be done shorthand but I wrote them out for clairity.

[demo on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v8auvtbu/13/)

```
<div class="header__form-contact--wrapper">
  <div class="header__form-contact">

    <div class="header__form-contact-input-left">
      <input type="text" placeholder="input 1" class="input">
      <input type="text" placeholder="input 2" class="input">
      <input type="text" placeholder="input 3" class="input">
    </div>

    <div class="header__form-contact-input-right">
      <input type="text" placeholder="input 1" class="input">
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="header__form-contact"></div>
</div>
```

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header__form-contact--wrapper {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #ededed;
  padding: .5rem;
}

.header__form-contact {
  display: flex;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  padding: .5rem;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  &:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: deeppink;
  }
}

.header__form-contact-input-left {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  padding: .5rem;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

.header__form-contact-input-right {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  padding: .5rem;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.input {
    border: none;
    padding: .2rem;
    margin-bottom: .2rem;

    &:last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dejan, Flex solution is great.

Answer (score 1):

Add display:table to .header__form-contact--wrapper and display:table-cell to &>div. Hopefully this will solve your problem.

or add white-space: nowrap; to .header__form-contact--wrapper and white-space: normal; vertical-align: top; to &>div

```
 .header__form-contact--wrapper{
  height: 200px;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  &>div{
    border: 1px red solid;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    white-space: normal;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please extend the answer and explain why inline-block gets broken on input elements, i'll mark it as answer.

Comment: @clusterBuddy having things side by side with inline is not always optimal. There are other way better answers then that. If you really want to learn html/css then let me know.

Comment: @Dejan.S put an answer up and i'll mark it as answer if you provide a detailed explanation on a better way, because that's what we are all here for, thanks.

Comment: @clusterBuddy sure but you would have to explain what you want a bit better, do you want the divs to be side by side, and child inputs to be 50 50 split on the inputs, should everything for child be center vertical and horizontal?

Comment: add  white-space: nowrap; to parent and white-space: normal;
vertical-align: top; to child. Actually When using inline-block elements, there will always whitespace issue between those elements (that space is about ~ 4px wide). @clusterBuddy